# Creating and filling database from a Controller (Symfony 2, Doctrine)

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

I am trying to create an installation Bundle for my Symfony 2.2.3 application.
Therefore I want to drop/create a database (mysql) and then create the schema via Controller Actions.

My Code:

```
$kernel = $this->get('kernel');
$application = new \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application($kernel);
$application->setAutoExit(false);

// drop old database
$options = array('command' => 'doctrine:database:drop', '--force' => true);
$application->run(new \Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput($options));

// create new database
$options = array('command' => 'doctrine:database:create');
$result = $application->run(new \Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput($options));

// check if database:create was successful, then create schema
if($result == 0) {
    $options = array('command' => 'doctrine:schema:create');
    $result = $application->run(new \Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput($options));
}
```

database:drop and database:create work fine (both commands return 0), but creating the schema then fails.

However, when I comment the first 2 commands out so that only doctrine:schema:create will be executed (if clause removed, of course) and reload the page *without changing anything else* the database schema will be created properly.

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Comment: try to make space between `new` and `\Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput($options)` line 16

Comment: sorry that was a c&p problem, i edited my question, thanks

Comment: do you have any error?

Comment: $application->run returns 0 if everything went fine or an error code (see http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.html#method_run) in my case, executing the command "doctrine:schema:create" returns 1 (and 0 the second time when everything worked)

Answer (score 1):

This code works (Symfony 2.7)

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;

/**
 * @Route("/resetDB", name="adminResetDB")
 */
public function resetDBAction()
{
    $application = new Application($this->get('kernel'));
    $application->setAutoExit(false);

    // Drop old database
    $options = array('command' => 'doctrine:database:drop', '--force' => true);
    $application->run(new ArrayInput($options));

    // Make sure we close the original connection because it lost the reference to the database
    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getConnection()->close();

    // Create new database
    $options = array('command' => 'doctrine:database:create');
    $application->run(new ArrayInput($options));

    // Update schema
    $options = array('command' => 'doctrine:schema:update','--force' => true);
    $application->run(new ArrayInput($options));

    // Loading Fixtures, --append option prevent confirmation message
    $options = array('command' => 'doctrine:fixtures:load','--append' => true);
    $application->run(new ArrayInput($options));

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('index'));
}
```